# How to get rid of extra elements in string literal in php?

Tags: php, string

I have number like `9843324+` and now I want to get rid of `+` at the end and only have `9843324` and so how should I do this in php ?

Right now I am doing `$customer_id = explode('+',$o_household->getInternalId);` also `$o_household->getInternalId` returns me  9843324+ but I want 9843324, how can I achieve this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you just want to pop the + off the end, use [`substr`](http://www.php.net/substr).

```
$customer_id = substr($o_household->getInternalId, 0, -1);
```

or [`rtrim`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php)

```
$customer_id = rtrim($o_household->getInternalId, "+");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regeular expression to remove anything that isn't a number

`$newstr = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/","",$str);`

Answer (score 1):

```
$customer_id = rtrim ( $o_household->getInternalId, '+' );
```

[rtrim function reference](http://at.php.net/manual/de/function.rtrim.php)

`rtrim` removes the characters in the second argument (`+` only in this case) from the end of a string.

In case there is no `+` at the end of the string, this won't mess up your value like `substr`.

This solution is obviously more readable and faster than, let's say `preg_replace` too.

Answer (score 0):

you could use intval($o_household->getInternalId)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you need to use explode? i would just use `substr` as Andy suggest or `str_replace`. Either would work for the example you provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can use intval to get the integer value of a variable, if possible:

```
echo intval($str);
```

Be aware that intval will return 0 on failure.