# How to get rid of string elements in php?

Tags: php, string

Customer id literal has customer_id+Domain_details, eg.: `998787+nl` and now I just want to have `998787` and not `+nl`, how can this be acheived this in php

Question:

I have number like `9843324+nl` and now I want to get rid of all elements including `+` and afterwards at the end and only have `9843324` and so how should I do this in php ?

Right now I am having `$o_household->getInternalId` returns me  `9843324+nl` but I want 9843324, how can I achieve this ?

Thanks.

Thanks.

**Update** :

```
    list($customer_id) = explode('+',$o_household->getInternalId());
```

Will this solve my problem ?

Comment: Rachel, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210347/how-to-get-rid-of-extra-elements-in-string-literal-in-php has the answer that you accepted. There is no difference between the two, why ask another question?

Comment: It does have difference, actually I wa about to refer that question in here

Comment: That answer does not remove domain details from customer id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$plusSignLoc = strpos($o_household->getInternalId, "+");
$myID = substr($o_household->getInternalId, 0, $plusSignLoc);

//Debug (Verification)
echo $myID;
?>
```

This will find the + sign, and insure that anything and everything after it will be removed.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to keep the leading zeros, simply convert it into an integer.

```
$theID = (int)"9843324+nl";
// $theID should now be 9843324.
```

If the `+` is just a separator and the sutff before can be a non-number, use

```
$val = "9843324+nl";
$theID = substr($val, 0, strcspn($val, '+'));
// $theID should now be "9843324".
```

Comment: I do not have leading zeros here, only customer_id+domain_name but I want to remote `+domain_name` and only have customer_id, hope I am making myself clear here.

Comment: @Rachel: `$theID` is your customer_id.

Answer (score 2):

Easy way? Just cast it to an int and it will drop off the extra stuff.

```
<?php
$s = '998787+nl';
echo (int)$s;
?>
```

Output:

```
998787
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need it to remain a string value, you can use [**`substr`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to cut the string down to its starting index to the 3rd from last character, omitting the domain details *`+nl`*

```
$customer_id = substr($o_household->getInternalId, 0, -3);
```

Answer (score 1):

As a slightly more general solution, this regular expression will remove everything that isn't a digit from the string `$str` and put the new string (set of numbers, so it can be treated as an integer) into `$num`

```
$num = preg_replace('/[^\d]/', '', $str);
```

Comment: @Downvoter, Please comment as to why. This works exactly as the questioner wanted and provides a good alternative to all the other methods suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [explode()](http://php.net/explode) function, and use `+` as your delimiter.